# With vuejs development in the ios browser environment can not get the value

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I use the vuejs components to develop the countdown component, in the pc and Andrews environment is normal, but in the ios environment because it can not get realcount calculation does not come out, NaN

```
    <template>
<div class="coutpage">
<div class="countheader">

</div>
  <ul class="countdowmlist" v-if="!countdowndata.over">
    <li v-text="countdowndata.days"></li>
    <li>天</li>
    <li v-text="countdowndata.hours"></li>
    <li>时</li>
    <li v-text="countdowndata.minus"></li>
    <li>分</li>
    <li v-text="countdowndata.second"></li>
    <li>秒</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="isover" v-if="countdowndata.over">
    时间到
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script type="text/ecmascript-6">
export default {
  name: 'Countdown',
  props: [ 'endDate' ],
  data () {
    return {
      countdowndata: {
        days: '0',
        hours: '0',
        minus: '0',
        second: '0',
        realcount: '0',
        over: false
      },
      interval: {}
    }
  },
  created () {
    const counttime = new Date(this.endDate).getTime() - new Date().getTime()
    if (counttime < 0) {
      clearInterval(this.interval)
      return
    }
    this.countdowndata.realcount = Math.floor(counttime / 1000)
    const _this = this
    this.interval = setInterval(function () {
      _this.getCount()
    }, 1000)
  },
  methods: {
    getCount () {
      var time = this.countdowndata.realcount
      if (time <= 0) {
        clearInterval(this.interval)
        this.countdowndata.over = true
        return
      }
      var days = Math.floor(time / 60 / 60 / 24)
      var hours = Math.floor((time - days * 60 * 60 * 24) / 60 / 60)
      var minus = Math.floor((time - days * 60 * 60 * 24 - hours * 60 * 60) / 60)
      var second = Math.floor((time - days * 60 * 60 * 24 - hours * 60 * 60 - minus * 60))
      hours = hours < 10 ? ('0' + hours) : hours
      minus = minus < 10 ? ('0' + minus) : minus
      second = second < 10 ? ('0' + second) : second
      this.countdowndata.days = days
      this.countdowndata.hours = hours
      this.countdowndata.minus = minus
      this.countdowndata.second = second
      this.countdowndata.realcount--
    }
  }

}
</script>
```

[in ios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bE4XX.jpg)

[in pc or android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79nqK.png)

i used the vuejs-cli + webpack +vue-router

Answer (score 0):

Consider using moment.js for date & time manipulations https://momentjs.com